# Fine Upload No File to upload

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader in my form using this : http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/forms.html.

The problem is that, in my form file field is optional.

If I send the form I have this and the form doesn't proceed:

[Error On submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoDPj.png)
And my js code :

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
      element: document.getElementById('my-uploader'),
      maxConnections:1,
      callbacks: {
          onAllComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
              location.reload();
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader is a file upload library. As such, you must provide it with files to upload. It is not a form submission library, and will not submit a form unless a file is involved. If you would like to submit a form without a file, you will need to omit attaching Fine Uploader to the form. Your best bet in this case is to allow the file to be sent independent of the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there are 0 files: in that case, don't trigger fineUploader "uploadStoredFiles" method. E.g.

```
    var fineUploaderTrigger = jQuery('<div id="fine-uploader"></div>');

    fineUploaderTrigger.fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        autoUpload: false,  /* important */

        [...]
    });

    var submitButton = $('#submit');

    // Trigger upload
    submitButton.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // go on also if there are no files to upload
        if ($('.qq-upload-list li').length > 0) {
            $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
        } else { 
            submitButton.off('click');
            submitButton.click();
        }
    });
```